# creating images catalogue app with python tkinter , the search will list the images files in the Listbox and display the image on tk.Label when click

Tags: python, image, tkinter, search

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os

window= Tk()
window.title("Catalogue Search")
height=600
width = 700
cavas= Canvas(window,height= height,width= width)
cavas.pack()


def searchfiles(extension,path):
    for d,r,f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                lw1.insert(0,r + '\\'+ file)
                print(file)

def open_file():
    os.startfile(lw1.get(lw1.curselection()[0]))
b5=Button(window,text"Search",command=lambda:searchfiles('.png', 
    (r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Share')))

b5.place(relx=0.12,rely = 0.3,relheight=0.04,relwidth=0.07,anchor="n")

lw1 = Listbox(window)
lw1.place(relx=0.27,rely = 0.35,relheight=0.5,relwidth=0.5,anchor ='n')

scr=Scrollbar(lw1)
scr.place(relx=0.47,relheight=1,relwidth=0.08)

lw1.config(lw1,yscrollcommand=scr.set)
scr.configure(command=lw1.yview)

im1= Label(lf1,bd=10,bg="black")
im1.place(relheight=1,relwidth=1)
im1.bind("<Double-Button>",lambda x:open_file())

window.mainloop()
```

I am trying to create an images catalogue app with python thinter, the search will list all the images files from the folder in the Listbox and once click and the clicked file will display the image in the Label

Comment: The code did not run , your contribution will highly be appreciated . thanks

Comment: You should give more details about the problem: do you get an error when you run the code? If yes, please add the error message and traceback to the question. If no, what do you get instead of the expected result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips about writing questions.

Comment: There are few issues: missing `=` between `text` and "Search" in the line `b5=Button(window,text"Search",...)`; undefined `lf1`.